# Turning off reactivity for contenteditable areas (Meteor)

Tags: meteor

I'm aware that you can turn off reactivity with `reactive: false` while fetching collections. How to accomplish the same with collection fields within, say, a contenteditable area? Example:

```
Template.documentPage.events({
  'input .document-input': (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    content = $(e.target).html();
    Documents.update(this._id, {
      $set: {
        content: content
      }
    });
   }
});

<template name="documentPage">
  <div class='document-input' contenteditable='true'>{{{content}}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Interesting. Since Blaze came out, reactivity will generally work fine with all kind of input elements, so I guess it should work for `contenteditable` as well. If it's not, then it's probably something that can be easily fixed in the meteor code base.

Comment: @apendua Blaze duplicates content in `contenteditable` areas: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1964

Answer (score 1):

to turn of reactivity of e.g. helpers or other reactive functions wrap your function with Tracker.nonreactive(fn). See: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_nonreactive

Comment: didn't work. I did something like `Tracker.nonreadtive(function(){ return @content });` in the `contenteditable` helper and Meteor threw a closed Websocket error.

Comment: Can you share a bit more code? It is hard to help you without seeing the whole picture

Answer (score 0):

you could set the reactive data to an attribute and move it to the html in onRendered

```
<template name="documentPage">
  <div class='document-input' contenteditable='true' data-content='{{content}}'></div>
</template>

Template.documentPage.onRendered(function () {
  var doc = this.find(".document-input");
  doc.innerHTML = doc.dataset.content;
});
```

That way the data-content attribute will be updated by blaze on input not the text of the element.

**SECURITY NOTE:** I changed the template to use `{{content}}` instead of `{{{content}}}` so it can be escaped by meteor but used `doc.innerHTML` so the content will be "unescaped" in the element. Any time you are rendering html from user input you should make sure you are sanitizing it so you don't open an [xss](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerability in your site.

The alternative would be to use a library like https://github.com/UziTech/jquery.toTextarea.js to change the editable content of a div to text and use `doc.textContent` in place of `doc.innerHTML` to remove any chance of xss